# How can I make a room feel bigger than it is?

Tags: cleaning

I've cleaned to make space for organizing the spot and adding shelves and I have still not felt the space is bigger than it is.

Comment: Too little information to help. What size is the room? What color are the walls? What are you allowed/not allowed to do in terms of painting or other changes? Any windows? What kind of lighting?

Comment: Are you able to paint the room or is this a dorm/apartment that you can't make changes to?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ways to make a room feel big (not a complete list):

- Cover one wall with mirrors - this may be extreme but it is effective. Even framed mirrors make a room feel larger.
- Increase the amount of light in the room
- Paint your walls a light color
- Reduce the amount of furniture/stuff in the room
- On wood or tile floors use an area rug that is smaller than normal
- Pull the furniture away from the wall
- Leave your windows uncovered

Hopefully one or more of these suggestions will help.

Answer (score 2):

1. Paint your walls and floor with light colors- this will give you the illusion of a bigger space.
2. Maximize your space by using hidden storage- By doing this, there will be less clutter in your room. Clutter actually makes space look small (and unorganized).
3. Install shelves close to the ceiling- to draw the eye upward.
4. Vertical shelves and storage- Take advantage of your vertical space. Horizontal shelves make your space look tight and crowded.
5. Small items in your room make it look crowded, get decorations that are big to give an illusion of a bigger space.
6. Uncover your windows to give a room depth.
7. Glass or acrylic materials make your space bigger.
8. Pieces of furniture with legs give it a spacious illusion.
9. Match colors with different shades for coordination.